# Ansible - Calculate the vars in when condition and select the closest value from ansible_facts

Tags: ansible

I am writing a ansible playbook to select unused disks from ansible_devices. If the server has more than one unused disks, I want to pick the one same as input size/or closest to it,  Size variable is user input.

following is my code:-

```
-name: Print disk result


   - "{{ min_value }}.00 GB" <= item.value.size <= "{{ max_value }}.00 GB"


   vars:
    min_value: "{{ size - 2 }}"
    max_value: "{{ size + 2 }}"
```

The item.value.size is like this for disks:-

"size": "50.00 GB" for disk1

"size": "5.00 GB" for disk2

I am getting this error:-

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'

The error appears to have been in '/home/bhatiaa/disk5.yml': line 25, column 32, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

     - not item.value.links.ids
     -
```

Comment: You may want to take a moment to properly format the code in your question so that it's a little more readable.  Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: Hello, I have tried formatting but it still display same, I have posted the error now in the original question

Comment: I have fixed the formatting.  You may want to spend some time reading the formatting help; people will often ignore or downvote questions that are hard to read because of formatting. Also, since the YAML syntax used by Ansible is sensitive to indentation, it's critical that what you post in your question exactly matches what you're using in your playbooks.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) also were you able to identify my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```
- "{{ min_value }}.00 GB" <= item.value.size <= "{{ max_value }}.00 GB"
```

There are a few problems here.  Fundamentally, you're trying to perform a numeric comparison (`<=`) on non-numeric values (`50.00 GB`, and that's never going to work.  But that's not the source of your error.  The error crops up because you're starting the value with a quote (`"`), so the YAML parser expects the entire line to be quoted, like this:

```
- '"{{ min_value }}.00 GB" <= item.value.size <= "{{ max_value }}.00 GB"'
```

That gets rid of your error message, but it's still problematic in several ways.  In addition to the "numeric comparison with non-numeric values" problem, in a `when` conditional you're already in a Jinja template context so you don't need the `{{` and `}}` markers.  You'd want to write the expression something like this:

```
- '"%s.00 GB" % min_value <= item.value.size <= "%s.00 GB" % max_value
```

But while syntactically correct, that still suffers from the first problem I identified.  we really need to come up with numeric values to use.  One option would be to assume that sizes are always specified in `GB` and just strip  it off, as in:

```
- min_value <= int(item.value.size[:-3]) <= max_value
```

Another option would be to calculate the disk size using `sectors` and `sectorsize` instead, like this:

```
- min_value <= (item.value.sectors * item.value.sectorsize) <= max_value
```

This would require `min_value` and `max_value` to be specified in bytes.

Hopefully there's enough here to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm going to restate what I said in my answer: inside a `when` condition you're already in a templating context; you don't need and should not use `{{...}}` markers.  If you want to update your question to show what your playbook looks like now (after fixing what I just mentioned), it will be easier to help you out. Comments aren't great for code samples.